# htaccess two case to redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Hello i need some help I am working with htaccess and I have problem with casing:

1. If requested uri contains .png, .jpg or .gif then redirect to index1.html?img=$1
2. Buf if requested uri doesn't contains these, then redirect to index2.html

My htaccess: (but always redirect to 2nd case)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond $1 (.png|.jpe?g|.gif|.css|.js|.txt)

    RewriteRule .*(.png|.jpe?g|.gif|.css|.js|.txt) index1.html?img=$1

    RewriteCond $1 !=(.png|.jpe?g|.gif|.css|.js|.txt)

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index2.html
</IfModule>
```

Can you help me? Thank.

Answer (score 0):

In case of no previous redirection it will falback to fifth line.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.*)(.png|.jpe?g|.gif|.css|.js|.txt)$ index1.html?img=$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index2.html
```

Comment: Still redirect in index2 even when I call ex. localhost/image.png.